# Как задать стили input'ам форм django?

Tags: django

Как задать стили `input`'ам форм `django`?
Вывожу в html так `form.as_p`

Answer (score 1):

Из [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances):

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'background-color: red;'}))
```